# Changing plotly dash_table datatable data value results in blank cells

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create a plotly interface where the user can upload a csv file without headers and upload a separate text file that contains the header.  The csv file will be shown in a table, and when the text file is selected and loaded, the column headers of the datatable will be replaced with the column headers contained within the text file.

I've tried two ways to do this:
The first is to have a div in app.layout and have a callback function return a datatable to that div.  Using this method, the data table loads correctly, but I cannot figure out how to reference and change the columns of this table.

The second way is to have a blank table in app.layout, and have a callback function return data with pandas to_dict().  With this method, I can reference the table by its id and change its columns.  However, when I run the callback function the resulting datatable is blank (although the number of rows seems to be correct).

This is the app.layout

```py
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Upload File'),

    dcc.Upload(
        id ='upload_data',
        children = html.Button('Select Data File', 
                id = 'load_data_button')
    ),

    html.H2('Upload Headers'),

    dcc.Upload(
        id ='upload_headers',
        children = html.Button('Select Headers File', 
                id = 'load_header_button')
    ),
    html.Div(id = 'my_headers'),
    html.Div(id = 'my_data'),

    html.Div(
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id = 'load_data_table'
        )
    )
])
```

While this is the callback in question

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('load_data_table', 'data'),
    [Input('upload_data', 'contents')]
)
def update_table(content):
    if content is not None:
        content_type, content_string = content.split(',')
        decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
        df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(decoded), header = None)

        return df.to_dict('records')

    else:
        return [{}]
```

This is the code for the second method I mentioned. As shown, the initial table data is not set, and the output is mapped to the data of the table.

I expected that data would appear in the table, but what actually happens is that the table cells are blank instead.  However, the number of rows is right(i.e. if my csv is 5 rows, it generates 5 rows of empty cells), which makes me think that something is sent through the callback, at least.

Would anyone know how to fix the two methods I mentioned or know of a better method to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a similar problem, and the solution for me was with the column `name` and `id` values. The `name` for each column is what it will display, which I think is what you'll need to change after the user adds the columns. The `id` for each column needs to match exactly the column name from the `df` you pass to the `data` prop of the table.

Likely, you have a mismatch between those values. When that happens, the data is "there", which is why you see the proper number of rows, but the table won't display it because the columns are wrong. If you have a separate callback for the `column` prop of the table, make sure that is sending the proper values.

Comment: You are correct, the column has an id property which must match the row for the data to appear.  The reason this happens for me is that callbacks seem to run when the page is loaded, so I am telling my callback to originally return something like [{}] for columns, which obviously does not have the ids that I need.  Do you happen to know of a way to better handle the callbacks on loading?

Comment: All of the callbacks will fire once when the page loads to initialize, and there isn't a way around that. You could try to set some different defaults. Maybe, for each column in the user's upload, you assign a default ID based on the index of the column (0, 1, 2, etc), and then set your default columns to match that. Once the user uploads the actual headers, then you can overwrite the defaults. Maybe the user could upload a file that includes the headers? Maybe that doesn't fit what you need. You could also consider waiting to display the table until you have the data and headers.

Comment: did you end up solving this?